# xcode 9 xcodebuild switch on keychain sharing and push notifications

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

How can I switch on Keychain Sharing and Push Notifications via xcodebuild (XCode 9)? Are there any variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is actually somewhat tricky to do directly via `xcodebuild`.  The **EASIEST** thing to do is exactly what Claudio says up there:  change the settings in your target's Capabilities section directly.  +1 to him!  Changes you make for capabilities within the target **WILL** get picked up in all of your builds by default, unless you use my methods below to explicitly change them during build time.

If you want to do this via `xcodebuild` only (without opening Xcode), then read further:

If we were talking about Build Settings (i.e. compile time options), then changing settings could be as easy as something like:

[`xcodebuild -workspace DmitryWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme "YourAppName" -showBuildSettings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178452/set-xcode-build-setting-from-terminal)

But since you're actually trying to modify entitlements & capabilities (whether an app has the ability to do certain things), the thing you really need to do is to have different `.entitlements` files that toggle these options.  An `.entitlement` file is basically just another name for a `plist` file and it typically looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>development</string>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.myke.TestingSomething</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Those two keys there are for push notifications and keychain sharing.

And to pick up the entitlements file via `xcodebuild`, you could do something like:

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist projectName.entitlements -archivePath test.xcarchive -exportPath .`

I haven't tried this last part myself (I'd rather do Claudio's solution for my own projects), but I read up on this solution via this [related blog posting](http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/xcodebuild-export-options-plist/).  Good luck!

Comment: Thank for answer Michael Dautermann! Yes, my question was about xcodebuild but not Xcode because i need use it in Teamcity. I'll try your decide.

Comment: Can I use two files projectName.plist and projectName.entitlements for a flag -exportOptionsPlist? For example: xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist projectName.plist projectName.entitlements -archivePath test.xcarchive -exportPath

Comment: If you run `xcodebuild -help` you'll see the options for the `exportOptionsPlist` file.  It does not appear to provide any way to specify entitlements, so I don't think the last bit will work in this answer.  The only entitlement that appears to be setable is `iCloudContainerEnvironment`

Answer (score 1):

On xcode, click on your project, then capabilities and finally switch on Keychain sharing and Push Notifications

[image]

Comment: Dmitry is actually asking about `xcodebuild`, which is the command line tool used to build Xcode projects.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by putting the entitlement file "push.entitlements" at the root and add the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS="push.entitlements" at the xcodebuild archive command.

xcodebuild archive -project yourproject -scheme yourscheme -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -archivePath \"yourpath" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=\"{$code_sign_identity}\" PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=\"{$provisioning_profile}\" CODE_SIGN_STYLE=\"Manual\" CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=\"push.entitlements\"

I got the idea from this post: [Post iOS10 / Xcode 8.0 "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" error after build for iTunes Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594073/post-ios10-xcode-8-0-missing-push-notification-entitlement-error-after-build)