# Change Default XCode Architecture

Tags: xcode, macos

In Xcode 12, the default architecture for building got changed to arm64.  This causes many things to not build.

In this instance, running `pip install psutil` fails to build with an "architecture not supported error".

How can I change the default build architecture for xcode 12?

Comment: "This causes many things to [not] build."

Answer (score 0):

Try removing arm64 from the "Valid architecture" under the build setting of your Xcode project

[image: Supported screenshot]

Comment: I mean without any project, since this affects things outside of xcode projects.

Comment: there seems to be no other way right now. This is also an active issue on the [psutil's github repo](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1832)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

#### xcodebuild -arch

If you have a folder with .xcodeproj file in it, you can run `xcodebuild -arch architecture <other options>` to use a particular arch.

#### Xcode build settings.

Use `VALID_ARCHS` and/or `ARCHS` environment variables to let Xcode use those settings.

It can be set via `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_*` also.

There are several undocumented variables also, which you can find by running `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` or adding a post build script with a no-op command, and *show env vars in build log* ticked.

If either of them has the bad arch set, just overwrite it.

- https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/itcaec37c2a6
- [Set xcode "build setting" from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178452/set-xcode-build-setting-from-terminal?rq=1)
- [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html